# How to validate record in database

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is check that the customerid exists in the database. If it exists then the order is submitted to the orders table. If customerid does not exist, it returns an error.

Trying to check the customers table to see if the customerid entered by the user exists, just don't know how to do this.
The code below i got from a different thread.

```
$checkid = "SELECT customerid FROM $tableName WHERE customerid = ".($customerid)."";
$check_ref = @mysql_query($check2,$connection) 
    or die("Couldn't execute check.<br>".mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($check_ref)<1){
    $login_err = "The Customer number you entered does not exist.";
    $error = "1";
```

Comment: This code is horrible. Please stop using it. `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. Don't suppress errors using `@`. Use prepared statements.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: "it returns an error" — Which one?

Comment: Use IDE. If you did, and  click on $checkid variable, you would see that it won't be highlited in mysql_query() function, because there's a different variable. Also enabling the reports (or not disabling them) would give you a good direction about your mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here goes:

1. Your query is stored in `$checkid`, yet you query `$check2`
2. You disable error reporting on `mysql_query`. This is wrong on too many levels.
3. What are those parens doing around `$customerid` in the string concatenation?

Comment: This code is something I found on another thread on this site. I started doing php with sql yesterday. If anyone has a way to do it that would be much appriciated. 

trying to make it work so that the customer enteres in their customerid, on submit the number input by the customer is checked to see if it exists in customers table. If exists, continue, if not it returns an error. 

mostly what i need help with is how to check the database for the customerid.

Comment: Start with a decent PHP tutorial. Then, do a decent MySQL tutorial. Then do a decent PHP/MySQL tutorial. This could be a good start: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: In general, copying and pasting code from internet, without knowing what it does is a Bad Idea.